# How to operate on json in grails session object

Tags: json, grails, groovy

i want to store in session object a json object  `session.setAttribute("myjson",myjson)`

where myjson has a structure like this:

```
{ 'name':'john', age: 23}
{ 'name':'doe', age: 44}
..etc
```

How can i do this and how can i retrieve this object lateron from `session.getAttribute('myjson')` and append a new value `{}` ?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  or what errors or problems have you encountered?

Comment: Also, why not store a list of Maps in the session, and convert to JSON if required?

Comment: i have also just figered out i can just use maps instead. Well i need some temp session data which will be deleted when the session invalidates. So i thought it's overkill to use mysql table since it's not persistent info i'm holding onto. Unless i can create temp. mysql table? But session object seemed like a good choice since i only would save max 10 objects in a map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to accomplish this, but honestly, you need to ask yourself "Is this really the right thing to do?". Why? Because storing anything in the session should be a last resort and should be kept to a bare minimum when you have to. Using the session in any HTTP environment **kills** performance and makes your application much more difficult to scale horizontally.

Keeping that in mind, you can always use `org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.json.JSONObject`s and the `grails.converters.JSON` converter to accomplish this. Though, using a `List` of `Map`s might be easier.

Comment: well i need to temporary holdon on some information like: client_session_id, client_app_id,..  and it would be about max 10 entries per session object. Either this or a temp sql table? How about a custom groovy collection class?

Comment: Then just store a map in the session and be done with it (until you end up having scalability problems and have to move to a db backed session storage).

Answer (score 1):

Just to give sample code:
You can use list of map as mentioned in the comment.

```
List<Map<String,Integer>> listInSesion = [] 
listInSession.add([ 'name':'john', age: 23])
listInSession.add([ 'name':'doe', age: 44])
.
.

session.setAttribute('listInSession',listInSession)
```

If you are getting the **JSON** from an **HTTP** request you can simply say:

```
listInSession = request.JSON
```

To get the list and add new ones:

```
listInSession = session.getAttribute('listInSession')
listInSession?.add([ 'name':'john', age: 23])
session.setAttribute('listInSession',listInSession)
```